# How to manage GCP/Google API Client calls that have over 500 results

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-api-python-client

Sample Python code below.  As expected, since '[maxResults](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/firewalls/list)' must be between 0 and 500, I get no more than 500 items back:

```
from googleapiclient import discovery

resource_object = discovery.build('compute', 'v1')
result = resource_object.firewalls().list(project="myproject-123456").execute()
print(len(result.get('items', [])))
500
```

But I know there are more than 500 items.

In AWS / boto3, this problem is solved via [Paginators](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/paginators.html).  Is there an equivalent in GCP?

Answer (score 0):

Found the way to do this is using [pageToken](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uB8ir0BzTLA).  Couldn't find any Python examples so here goes:

```
PROJECT_ID = "myproject-123456"

results = []
page_token = None
while True:
    result = resource_object.firewalls().list(project=PROJECT_ID, pageToken=page_token).execute()
    results.extend(result.get('items', []))
    page_token = result.get('nextPageToken')
    if not page_token:
        break
```